# Auto-renewable subscriptions supported iOS version

Tags: iphone

What versions of iOS support auto-renewable subscriptions? Can I use it with 3.1.3?

Comment: Pretty sure it's only been in since 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the answer on stack overflow.

[What is the minimum target iOS version for auto-renewable subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667856/what-is-the-minimum-target-ios-version-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions/6917058#6917058)