# What is the minimum target iOS version for auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, subscription

Is there a minimum version of iOS that is needed to support auto-renewable subscriptions? I know that feature was introduced in iOS 4.3 but I don't see anything about it that would seem to force it to only work on 4.3 and later devices. Has anyone successfully implemented auto-renewable subscriptions on older versions of iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually an engineer at Apple provided an answer:

Auto-renewable subscriptions will only work on iOS 4.2 and above.

Comment: What happened in [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556177/client-connection-immediately-closed)?  I was working on helping you and then you just deleted it.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm sorry! I didn't realize you were working on it. I resolved the issue - it was that another socket server was being linked to the same http server. Since it seemed like such weird edge case it didn't seemed like it was going to help anyone else to leave it up

Comment: Well, you and I had gone back and forth several times working on it. It's common courtesy to at least let me know what the problem ended up being.  In that specific case, you could have filed your own answer because that is actually an interesting problem that could happen to others.  Not super common, but could happen.  It felt like we were having a phone conversation about your problem and you just hung up on me.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thank you for your help and sorry for the abrupt deletion. I really didn't think you were still engaged with it or that it would be of help to others.